# hide div when there is no ad impression

Tags: adsense

I am using Adsense on my website. google is giving ad only fo 30% of the pageviews. and for rest of 70% of pageviews it shows a  big white screen.
I want to smartly handle this 70% case and hide this div or show some other static content. how can I do that?

```
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- responsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9299753465943567"
     data-ad-slot="6570418376"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script> 
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Adsense and select your ad unit.  At the bottom  you will see a dropdown by name "IF NOT AVAILABLE".
Here I choose "Show Other URL" and given a link to my internal HTML Page.

Even After doing it I was not getting my  page.   Later I realised that its because my website was HTTPS and the html was put under HTTP URL. 
So that was the actual problem.

I am coping my HTML  page content for other developers .

```
<htmL>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a target="_blank" href="mylink">
<img src="Some-image.jpg" style="width:80%;">
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the option of "collapse the Ad unit otherwise show blank space" and i have noticed that i either get an Ad or a blank space. It never collapses. Have you faced such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/113262?hl=en) might be of help:

> You can choose what happens to your ad unit if Google has no targeted
>   ads are available. By default, Google will try to collapse the ad
>   space on your page or if that's not possible show a blank space.
>   Alternatively, you can choose to display a solid color or another HTML
>   page. This way, you can make sure that your advertising space is
>   always being used effectively.
>
> When you create or edit an ad unit, in the "If no ads available"
>   section, choose one of the following options:
>
> Collapse ad unit, otherwise show blank space This is the default
>   option.
>
> Collapse ad unit, otherwise show color You can effectively make your
>   unfilled ad unit disappear by matching its color to the background
>   color of your page. You can either use the color picker or enter a
>   hexadecimal color code.

Normally Google will try to collapse the ad space.  If not, you can opt to show an image of your choice. See "show other URL" part of the linked page.